# Validation failed for query for method public abstract & [Entity] is not mapped

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate and Spring to create a Rest Api. 
I'm mapping a Trainer to a table in mySQL

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List io.fruitful.model.repos.TrainerRepository.getTrainerByFilter(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
```

and

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: trainers is not mapped [SELECT t from trainers t WHERE t.trainerName = :name AND t.accountId = :id]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
... 79 common frames omitted
```

Entity:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "trainers")
public class Trainer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "trainer_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer trainerId;

    @Column (name = "trainer_name")
    private String trainerName;

    @Column (name = "account_id")
    private Integer accountId;
```

Here is the Repo code:

```
     @Query(value = "SELECT t from trainers t WHERE t.trainerName = :name AND t.accountId = :id")
List<Trainer> getTrainerByFilter(@Param("name") String name,
                                 @Param("id") Integer id);
```

@Query(value = "SELECT * from trainers where account_id is null", nativeQuery = true)
    List getTrainerNoAccount();

ConfigSql:

```
    environment.setPackagesToScan("io.fruitful.model");
```

The *getTrainerNoAccount()* is working fine.

Comment: read JPA documentation. JPQL uses entity names. It is not SQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate maps your entity as `Trainer`, the name of your class, since you didn't specified the name param in @Entity annotation.
Thus, your query should be "SELECT t from **Trainer** t...".

`getTrainerNoAccount()` works fine because its @Query is set as native, using the table name and not your entity name.

Answer (score 1):

```java
 @Query(value = "SELECT t from Trainer t WHERE t.trainerName = :name AND t.accountId = :id")
List<Trainer> getTrainerByFilter(@Param("name") String name,
                                 @Param("id") Integer id);
```

Change your Query like that because JPA needs bean name rather table name.